# I was trying to deploy contract for pinata ipfs Image and getting error

Tags: solidity, hardhat-deploy

I was trying to deploy contract for pinata ipfs and getting error

```
Nothing to compile
Local network detected! Deploying mocks...
deploying "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock" (tx: 0x72a894d215f348b1e3a4d1665d1332c1096776aa1d6f2d3b0dacaafb1ae71b7f)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 2527447 gas
deploying "MockV3Aggregator" (tx: 0xd9e49ed1669511270e91820ad94ce98c80245b62adb286689e88a0e39436e096)...: deployed at 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512 with 569795 gas
Mocks Deployed!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
You are deploying to a local network, you'll need a local network running to interact
Please run `npx hardhat console --network localhost` to interact with the deployed smart contracts!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
----------------------------------------
deploying "BasicNFT" (tx: 0x2ca88743caa4671f3b78bfa9e80102c0393a9cd27aba27575b5a68d707af2b62)...: deployed at 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0 with 2045285 gas
----------------------------------------
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\deploy\02-deploy-random-ipfs-nft.js:
TypeError: deployScript.func is not a function
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1220:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1053:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:422:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:330:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:163:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:568:32)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1223:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1053:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:422:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:330:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:163:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\kharw\OneDrive\Documents\solidity\NFTs\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:568:32)
```

This is Pinata code

```
const pinataSDK = require('@pinata/sdk')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const pinataApiKey = process.env.PINATA_API_KEY
const pinataApiSecret = process.env.PINATA_API_SECRET
const pinata = pinataSDK(pinataApiSecret, pinataApiKey)

async function  storeImages(imagesFilePath){
    const fullImagesPath = path.resolve(imagesFilePath)
    const files = fs.readdirSync(fullImagesPath)
    let responses = []
    console.log("Uploading to IPFS...")
    for(fileIndex in files){
        const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream(`${fullImagesPath}/${files[fileIndex]}`)
        try{
            const response = await pinata.pinFileToIpfs(readableStreamForFile)
            responses.push(response)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    return {responses, files}
}

module.exports = {storeImages}
```

This is the deploy code

```
const { network } = require("hardhat");
const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");
const { storeImages } = require("../utils/UploadTOPinata.js")
require("dotenv").config()

const imagesLocation = "./images/randomNft"
module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const chainId = network.config.chainId;
  let tokenUris
  if ( process.env.UPLOAD_TO_PINATA == "true"){
    tokenUris = await handleTokenUris()
  }


  let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId;

  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract(
      "VRFCoorditnatorV2Mock"
    );
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address;
    const tx = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription();
    const txReceipt = awaittx.wait(1);
    subscriptionId = txReceipt.events[0].args.subId;
  } else {
    (vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]), vrfCoordinatorV2;
  }

  log("------------------------------------");
  await storeImages(imagesLocation)
//   const args = [
//     vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
//     subscriptionId,
//     networkConfig[chainId].gasLane,
//     networkConfig[chainId].callbackGasLimit,
//   ];
};

async function handleTokenUris() {
    tokenUris = []

}

module.exports = ["all", "randomipfs", "main"]
```